# Closing Sockets/Stop Tasks on channel exit/close

Tags: roku, brightscript

i am getting starting with Roku development and after playing around with examples and reading through the docs, forums etc i've noticed that there is no app close/exit event handling through app code or handling the Home button etc...

With that in mind i have the following situation:

I start a component Task that opens a TCP socket/connection and listens for some custom commands i send. The Task of course runs in a loop waiting and reading the data as it comes through the socket, updates the app UI and so on...  (similar to this example https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roStreamSocket  just without allowing multiple connections)

How am i supposed to handle closing the TCP socket/port if i am unable to catch the app/exit close events?

**Should i even worry about that on the Roku/BrightScript side, are the sockets automatically closed and Tasks stopped?** (i've noticed that the rerunning the app after pressing Home successfully opens the socket connection on the same port so i guess that it got closed properly, but still it kinda feels wrong without any code handling :))

I've seen on this example https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roDataGramSocket  that it says :

```
udp.close()  ' would happen automatically as udp goes out of scope
```

Which leads me to believe that the closing happens automatically when the app closes. (as with some tests i implemented)

**Am i getting this right? :)**  Is so all i need to do is implement some ping/pong events for the client side to be able to detect that the Roku app socket got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tasks are getting stopped and sockets closed on app exit, memory is released etc. There is a tear-down/cleanup happening